Necessary and sufficient conditions of the set of interior angles of a polygon
Question
Can we find a set of conditions such that for any set $A$ satisfying these conditions, a polygon can be constructed whose set of interior angles is equal to $A$, and for any polygon $P$, the set of interior angles of $P$ satisfies these conditions?
There are a few obvious necessary and sufficient conditions:

$A$ is finite and real-valued

Let $|A| = n$.

Then $\sum_{a \in A} = 180(n-2)$

$0<a<360 \: \forall \: a \in A$

$180 \notin A$


Is this list exhaustive? Are there any more necessary and sufficient conditions that need to be added to this list?

Is the last one not a direct consequence of the second one? Imagine $n=5$, then you know that the sum should be $3 \cdot 180=540$. Now imagine that three or more are larger than $180$, how can you still get to $540$ as the sum? :-)

What's the problem with any angle being $180°$ (please add the °-sign in order to see the difference with radians)) I have no problem seeing a triangle as a quadrilateral with one angle being $180°$.

@Dominique Yes you are right

@Dominique An angle of 180 is a straight line, hence not an interior angle.

@Dominique lmao thinking about it, a triangle can be explained as an n sided polygon with n-3 angles having value 180°

I suppose we are talking about simple polygons (not self-intersecting) in order to define what an “interior” angle is.

@DavidK Yes, simple polygons
